# Chained selects for jQuery crash class select option

Tags: javascript, jquery

i'd problem to implemented Chained selects for jQuery.
I used reference from http://appelsiini.net/projects/chained/, it's work with this code :

```
    <label class="control-label" for="nama_hukuman">Area</label>
        <div class="controls">
          <select data-placeholder="Regional Area.." class="chzn-select" style="width:300px;" tabindex="2" name="area" id="area">
            <option value=""></option>
             <option value="SUMBAGSEL" <?php if($area == 'SUMBAGSEL'){echo "selected";} ?> >SUMBAGSEL</option>
             <option value="KALIMANTAN" <?php if($area == 'KALIMANTAN'){echo "selected";} ?> >KALIMANTAN</option>
             <option value="BALINUSRA" <?php if($area == 'BALINUSRA'){echo "selected";} ?> >BALINUSRA</option>
             <option value="SULAWESI" <?php if($area == 'SULAWESI'){echo "selected";} ?> >SULAWESI</option>
             <option value="MALIRJA" <?php if($area == 'MALIRJA'){echo "selected";} ?> >MALIRJA</option>
          </select>
    </div>
    <label class="control-label" for="nama_hukuman">Cluster</label>
        <div class="controls">
          <select data-placeholder="Cluster Area.." class="chzn-select" style="width:300px;" tabindex="2" name="cluster" id="cluster">
          <option value=""></option>
             <option value="Kalimantan Timur" data-chained="KALIMANTAN">Kalimantan Timur</option>
             <option value="Bali" data-chained="BALINUSRA">Bali</option>
             <option value="Lombok" data-chained="BALINUSRA">Lombok</option>
          </select>
    </div>
```

js :

```
<script src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>asset/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>asset/bootstrap/js/application.js"></script>
<script src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>asset/bootstrap/js/bootstrap-tooltip.js"></script>
<script src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>asset/bootstrap/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>asset/bootstrap/js/jquery.chained.min.js"></script>
<script src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>asset/bootstrap/js/chosen.jquery.js"></script>    

<script charset=utf-8>
  $(function(){
      $("#cluster").chained("#area");
  });
 </script>
```

Before i add jquery.min.js and jquery.chained.min.js my selected views like this :[image]

But after i add, my selected form changed into this :[image]

as my information above, i lost my selected format form chosen.jquery, is there any advise to give me solution with this problem??
THanks b4

Comment: add rendered html in code in OP.

Comment: Any error is console ?

Comment: @guradio what do you mean?

Comment: @MayankPandeyz there's no error, i just lost my previous format form in chosen.jquery.js, it because crash with jquery.min.js

Comment: **crash** means jquery conflict ?

Comment: @MayankPandeyz, not conflict, as my capture above, my format form was changed after i added jquery.min.js and jquery.chained.min.js for function chain selected, i want make chain selected in my web, i refer it from http://appelsiini.net/projects/chained/, but i had issue after i added chain selected jquery, my old selected form format was changed (see picture before and after)

Comment: Dont mind, but why you are using this plug-in. Any specific requirement ?

Comment: @MayankPandeyz if you there any reference, please inform, i just want make chain selected form, like after i select country, then state or city form show up, but without connection with database, i found solution in this plug-in, if you had some reference, let me know, thanks..

Comment: This can be achieved without using any plugin. Just to show the dropdown as you want you can check: https://www.sitepoint.com/13-jquery-selectboxdrop-down-plugins/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146486/discussion-between-mayank-pandeyz-and-karisma).